# Specific result in many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, eloquent, relationship

I hope to find an answer here,
I have a Group, Users, and participants table, Groups and participants are linked to an user with One-To-Many relation. 
Np with that.

Now I have a group_participant table, which is supposed to link participant to a group, with 3 columns:

1. id
2. group_id
3. participant_id

What i would like to do is to get the list of participants which are not part of the group, i can easily get the whole list, but i want to filter this one in order to only get the ones which are not related to the group.

I'm kinda stuck with many to many relations, i have my Group.php model which contains :

```
    public function participantsGroup()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Participant');
}
```

And if I do this :

```
public function participants(){

    $group = Group::find('group_id_there')->participantsGroup;
    return $group;
}
```

I'm getting the participant list related to this group, but what i want is the inverse of this, pls how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this you should use the `whereNotIn()` method, and pass an array of the current participants. Example:

```
// Fetch the participants in the group
$groupParticipantsId = Group::find(1)->participantsGroup()->lists('participant_id');
// Query to get all participants that are not in that group
$participantsNotInGroup = App\Participant::whereNotIn($groupParticipantsId)->get();
```

Best practice is to create a `scope` on the Class that makes more sense to you, I'll create the scope on the `App\Participant` class:

```
public function scopeNotInGroup($query, App\Group $group) {
    $participants = $group->participantsGroup()->lists('participant_id');
    return $query->whereNotIn($participants);
}
```

Then anywhere in your app you can do this:

```
// Fetch the participants in the group
$group = Group::find(1);
// Query to get all participants that are not in that group
$participantsNotInGroup = App\Participant::notInGroup($group)->get();
```

Comment: Yes thanks, just i have one last little question, a last problem. Groups are linked to User, like Participants so this solution displays all participants event those who are not linked to specific user, not regarding to user_id of participants table. So the perfect would be to display participants attached to the user i want, i don't know if i explain myself well..

Comment: I think I get the point, you mean all participants that the user have that do not belong to a specific group? Can you specify how is the relation between the `User`, `Group`, and `Participants` table, need that information in order to help you with that query.

Comment: Sure, so i have Group table related to user with admin_id and Participants related to user with user_id, both in One to Many. So the list i get contains all participants not regarding user_id, ideally if i have Group with id 1, which is related to admin_id 5 (it's an example) i would like to get only participants with user_id 5. Hope you see what i mean

Comment: Sure! There are a lot of different ways to do this. The simplest way to accomplish this is by adding a `where()` method to the call, something like this: `App\Participant::notInGroup($group)->where('user_id', $group->admin_id)->get();` . Keep in mind that if this is something you end up doing a lot you might want to extract it to a `scope` or just add this to the `scopeNotInGroup()` method.